# MongoDB last 30 days data

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have this data in a mongo database,

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5654a8f0d487dd1434571a6e"
    },
    "ValidationDate": {
        "$date": "2015-11-24T13:06:19.363Z"
    },
    "DataRaw": " WL 00100100012015-08-28 02:44:17+0000+ 16.81 8.879  1084.00",
    "ReadingsAreValid": true,
    "locationID": " WL 001",
    "Readings": {
        "pH": {
            "value": 8.879
        },
        "SensoreDate": {
            "value": {
                "$date": "2015-08-28T02:44:17.000Z"
            }
        },
        "temperature": {
            "value": 16.81
        },
        "Conductivity": {
            "value": 1084
        }
    },
    "HMAC": "ecb98d73fcb34ce2c5bbcc9c1265c8ca939f639d791a1de0f6275e2d0d71a801"
}
```

My goal is to calculate temperature, ph and conductivity values that satisfy a given range for the last 30 days but i am getting an error which i have not been able to resolve while searching online. Here is my code.

```
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient


def total_data_push():
    data = MongoClient().cloudtest.test_5_27

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    last_30d = now - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    last_year = now.replace(year=now.year - 1)

    since_last_month = data.find({"ReadingsAreValid": False}, {"ValidationDate": {"$gte": last_30d}},
        {"Readings.temperature.value": {"$gt": 1.0}}).count()

    print since_last_month

def main():
    total_data_push()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When i run the script without the ValidationDate piece, it returns correct values but adding this data component to get that for last 30 days returns the following error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "total_data_push.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "total_data_push.py", line 26, in main
    total_data_push()
  File "total_data_push.py", line 17, in total_data_push
    {"Readings.temperature.value": {"$gt": 1.0}}).count()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 866, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 90, in __init__
    raise TypeError("skip must be an instance of int")
TypeError: skip must be an instance of int
```

What am i really missing here? thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I've never used Mongodb from python so I'm not sure if the client library changes the signature of the find method but the mongo collection.find only accepts 2 parameters, the filter and the projection. You seem to have 3 different filter objects defined instead of one combined 

    { {
  "ReadingsAreValid": False
 },
 {
  "ValidationDate": {
   "$gte": last_30d
  }
 },
 {
  "Readings.temperature.value": {
   "$gt": 1.0
  }
 }
    }

Answer (score 3):

As said @BenCr, if you look at [`find` signature](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) :

> find(filter=None, projection=None, skip=0, limit=0,
>   no_cursor_timeout=False, cursor_type=CursorType.NON_TAILABLE,
>   sort=None, allow_partial_results=False, oplog_replay=False,
>   modifiers=None, manipulate=True)

The `filter` is the first parameter as the following :

```
since_last_month = db.data.find({
    "ReadingsAreValid": False,
    "ValidationDate": {"$gte": last_30d},
    "Readings.temperature.value": {"$gte": 1.0}
    }).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This filter should like:

```
since_last_month = db.data.find({
"ReadingsAreValid": False,
"ValidationDate": {"$gte": last_30d},
"Readings.temperature.value": {"$gte": 1.0}
}).count()
```